# UDF'S Using Java to dynamically build SQL based on UDF's parameters

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have a POC to use UDF's to dynamically build a sql query, execute it to create a table using various joins and selects. We need to share the UDF across various SF instances.

I tried using SQL but identifier does not resolve. So, starting using JAVA. I can now reference parameters. However, I cannot figure out how to execute the SQL within the JAVA udf.

What libraries do I need? Does anyone have an example of UDF/JAVA executing SQL in SF.

I appreciate any help with this.

Thanks
Norberto

Comment: have you looked at Snowflake Scripting, the power of SQL or Javascript and it all rather nice and simple https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

Comment: Here is some dynamic javascript store procedure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71550998/is-if-exists-supported-in-snowflake-stored-procedures

Comment: You cannot run SQL statements in Java UDFs. You will need to use a stored procedure. For simple stored procedures, SQL Script will do (it is still in preview). For more complex procedures or if you need a GA solution, you can use a JavaScript SP.

Comment: or here is some examples of snowflake scripting in action: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71549976/snowflake-data-unloading-multiple-tables/71552286#71552286

Comment: Please share your code, say what you mean by "tried using SQL but identifier does not resolve". Give us a problem we can reproduce, and we'll be able to help you. If you just want examples, go to the docs.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. They helped me greatly.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I tried this: create or replace function retcount(TABLEIN string, TABLEOUT string,TYPE string, LISTS string, REPORTABLE string, VERSION string)
    returns numeric(18,0)
    as
    $$
     select count(*) from IDENTIFIER($TABLEIN)
    $$
    ;  but it does not compile because of the $TABLEIN. I want the UDF to use the parameters to dictate what I want done.  So that's why I used JAVA UDF since it allows me to reference the parameters. I hope this example makes more sense.

Comment: Please start a new question, include the code and error messages

Comment: So, as I researched the information you all posted I finally ended up using SQL UDTF https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-tabular-functions.html So far so good. Thank you again.